# Solving $y'=\frac{1 + y^2 - x^2}{2 x y}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need help to solve the equation

$$y'=\frac{1 + y^2 - x^2}{2 x y}$$

Can I transform it into a homogeneous equation?

Actually this problem came from Apostol's *Calculus I*, 8.28.3

> Find the orthogonal trajectories of $x^2 + y^2 + 2 C y = 1$.

So it is better not to use anything beyond Chapter 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{1+y^2-x^2}{2xy}
\\2xydy &= dx+ y^2dx-x^2dx
\\x^2dx &=y^2dy-2xydy+dx
\\\frac{y^2dx-2xydy}{x^2}&=dx-\frac{dx}{x^2}
\\\frac{y^2dx-xd(y^2)}{x^2}&=dx-\frac{dx}{x^2}
\\-d\left(\frac{y^2}{x}\right)&=dx-\frac{dx}{x^2}
\end{align}$$

Now integrating,
$$-\frac{y^2}{x} = x+\frac{1}{x}+c
\\y^2+x^2+cx=-1
$$

Comment: I think $1+y^2+x^2$ should be rectified to $1+y^2-x^2$

Comment: @lab battacharjee Oh, whoops! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Hints, rewrite the equation as:

$$\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{y}{2x}  =  -\frac{x^2-1}{2 x y}$$

- Let $v = y^2$, so $\displaystyle \frac{dv}{dx} = 2 y \frac{dy}{dx}$
- After a bit of work, you will be able to find an integrating factor.
- Substitute back in after solving for $v$ and get final solution.

Comment: GREAT hints! $\operatorname{up}(+ 1)$

Comment: @Amzoti: Thanks my friend. You always make me positive.